# Como ordenar um array de objetos em java

Tags: java, array, int, classificação

Olá, tenho uma classe times onde eles possuem pontuação (`int`), número de vitórias (`int`), derrotas (`int`) etc. Dentro do método `main`, possuo um array de 20 times e preciso ordená-los pela pontuação, caso a pontuação seja igual verifico quem tem mais vitórias e preciso imprimir isto na tela. Se alguém poder ajudar ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Eduardo, bem vindo ao SOPt. Acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour. Para a tua pergunta ser respondida adequadamente aqui, você precisa postar parte de teu código. A comunidade ajuda, mas não faz para nós o que precisamos. São inúmeras e diferentes as possibilidades de solução nestas questões amplas, é preciso haver "por onde começar" para poder te ajudar com um problema ou dificuldade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente usar o método [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) assim:

```
Time[] times = ...;
Arrays.sort(times, (a, b) -> {
   int pa = a.getPontos();
   int pb = b.getPontos();
   return pa == pb ? a.getVitorias() - b.getVitorias() : pa - pb;
});
```

Só certifique-se antes de que não há nenhum elemento `null` no array, ou então esse código vai dar um `NullPointerException`.

No final, para imprimir os nomes, após a ordenação, basta usar um `for` simples e imprimir os nomes dos times um a um.